# API built with Flask and Gunicorn on local server not responding to request from client with jQuery but responds to Postman

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, request, gunicorn

I have the following jQuery code in my frontend app to make a POST request:

```
    $("#sendbutton").click(function(){
        console.log("Clicked")
        console.log(request_data)
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: request_data,
            crossDomain:true,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                console.log('Exception:', exception);
            }
        });

    });
```

With this code, I don't see my server receiving the request and the client shows the following message after some time:

[image]

and later this: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

If I make the same request to Postman, the server receives the request just fine and returns a response as expected. In case this helps, I've included what a successful request header looks like by printing `request.headers` on my server (which is running a Flask application wrapped with gunicorn):

```
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.21.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: <token> 
Host: localhost:8000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 50
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be from having https://localhost:8000/api instead of http://localhost:8000/api.